# Determine if a task is defined in an external build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a gradle task that is created at runtime to call another task ("myOtherTask") which is in a separate gradle file. The problem is if that other task doesn't exist an exception will be thrown. Is it possible to check that a task exists in an external gradle file before attempting to call it?

Example:

```
  task mainTaskBlah(dependsOn: ':setupThings')
    task setupThings(){
    //...
    createMyOtherTask(/*...*/)
    //...
}
def createMyOtherTask(projName, appGradleDir) {
    def taskName = projName + 'blahTest'
    task "$taskName"(type: GradleBuild) {
        buildFile = appGradleDir + '/build.gradle'
        dir = appGradleDir
        tasks = ['myOtherTask']
    }
    mainTaskBlah.dependsOn "$taskName"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can check if the tasks exists.  For example if we wanted to simulate this we could make the task creation triggered by a command line property

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = 'com.jbirdvegas.q41227870'
version = '0.1'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
}

// if user supplied our parameter (superman) then add the task
// simulates if the project has or doesn't have the task
if (project.hasProperty('superman')) {
    // create task like normal
    project.tasks.create('superman', GradleBuild) {
        println "SUPERMAN!!!!"
        buildFile = project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/build.gradle'
        dir = project.projectDir.absolutePath
        tasks = ['myOtherTask']
    }
}

// check if the task we are interested in exists on the current project
if (project.tasks.findByName('superman')) {
    // task superman exists here we do whatever work we need to do
    // when the task is present
    def supermanTask = project.tasks.findByName('superman')
    project.tasks.findByName('classes').dependsOn supermanTask
} else {
    // here we do the work needed if the task is missing
    println "Superman not yet added"
}
```

Then we can see both uses cases rather easily

```
$ ./gradlew -q build -Psuperman
SUPERMAN!!!!
$ ./gradlew -q build
Superman not yet added
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see how this is helping. My goal was to determine if 'myOtherTask' is defined in the project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/build.gradle' buildfile.

Comment: This illustrates the point.  If `project.tasks.findByName('myOtherTask')==null` then the task is not defined.  I just named the task differently. `if (project.tasks.findByName('superman')) { \* is defined *\ }`.  You wouldn't really want to try and parse a build.gradle file manually when the gradle build system has this information available.

Comment: But how do I call project.tasks.findByName('myOtherTask') when myOtherTask is (possibly) defined in a build.gradle file completely external to the above, hence the calling of it via a GradleBuild task.  'myOtherTask' my or may not be defined in    project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/build.gradle', and if it isn't I don't want to attempt to call it.

Comment: if the task is applied to the project then it doesn't matter what contributed the task.  For example the above would work if the task was added by a plugin, another script or something else.  They all contribute to the same project.  Now if you have submodules then that's a little different.  But the `project` without submodules is always the same project object.  If your using submodules then you can reference that project's `project` object from your code `rootProject.project('someOtherProject').tasks.findByName('someOtherProjectsTask')`

Comment: Slight add to the above.  Timing of tasks added and queried here matters.  So if your task creation is delayed till `afterEvaluate` or something of that nature then it will never exist during the configuration stage

Answer (score 2):

This won't help you find if the task is in a *specific* external file, but if you just want to determine if a task is *defined* in *any* of your imported gradle files...

From `gradlew help` I see there is a `tasks` task.

Sadly, `gradlew tasks` doesn't always show *all* taks. Some of my projects have an `integrationTest` task while others do not, in which case I can only go as far as `build`. However, the default `tasks` command lists `integrationTestClasses` but not `integrationTest`.

From `gradlew help --task tasks` I can see there is a report expanding `--all` parameter that we can use.

Now, I can see all tasks via `gradlew tasks --all`, so a simple `grep` can tell me whether or not the task I want exists. In bash, this might look like:

```
TASK="integrationTest"
if gradlew tasks --all | grep -qw "^$TASK"
then
    gradlew clean integrationTest
else
    gradlew clean build
fi
```

---

FYI --
Personally, I needed something to tell me in a git pre-commit hook whether the `integrationTest` task existed or not, so I know whether I can run `gradlew integrationTest` or if I have to stop at `gradlew build`. Not finding an answer here, I kept looking, and this is what I came up with to solve my problem. Hopefully, this is of use to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little "tool" for stuff like that - maybe it comes in handy for some of you...

```
$ cat if_gradle_task_exists
#!/bin/sh

TASKS=$(./gradlew tasks --all)
BUILD="./gradlew "

for COMMAND in $@; do
        echo "$TASKS" | grep -q "$COMMAND" && BUILD="$BUILD $COMMAND"
done
$BUILD
```

You can append as many tasks as you like and only the existing ones are executed.

I use it in combination with `alias` as a kind of super api wrapper for tasks I want to be done in different projects (and I don't want to have to care if any of the specific tasks really do exist):

```
alias ge='~/.config/bin/if_gradle_task_exists eclipse initDb createTestUsers startLdapServerMock startBrokerMock'
```

That allows me to be as lazy as `ge`

```
stumpf@HV000408:/c/devel/workspace/myproject $> ge
```

to set up the project for eclipse and prepare all needed servers for local development.

The list of tasks produced will need some time to be set-up, so I wouldn't recommend to use it as a full `gradlew` wrapper though.

Regards