# Gradle SubProject tasks are not getting picked-up

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-module setup for a Java project with following structure.

```
mainApp
|--> core-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|       
|--> lib-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> lib-another-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> settings.gradle
|--> build.gradle
```

in `mainApp/build.gradle` I've mentioned

```
subprojects {
    test.dependsOn "CreateMessageKeys"
    //test.dependsOn ":CreateMessageKeys"
    //test.dependsOn ("CreateMessageKeys")
    //test.dependsOn (":CreateMessageKeys") none of this working....

}

task CreateMessageKeys(type: CreateMessageKeysTask) {
    destDir = "bundle-common/src/";
    outputClass = "common.messages.MessageKeys";
}
```

and my `core-module/build.gradle` have a test target as

```
test {
    useTestNG() { 
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites 'test/testng.xml' 
    }
}
```

but getting error as below.. What Am I missing here?

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.dependsOn() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [CreateMessageKeys]
Possible solutions: respondsTo(java.lang.String)
```

**Edit**

```
subprojects {
    test.dependsOn(rootProject.tasks['CreateMessageKeys'])
}

task CreateMessageKeys(type: CreateMessageKeysTask) {
    destDir = "bundle-common/src/";
    outputClass = "common.messages.MessageKeys";
}
```

It generates the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myApp'.
> Task with name 'CreateMessageKeys' not found in root project 'mainApp'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The task definition does not look correct, see [defining tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks).

It should look like this:

```
task ('CreateMessageKeys', type: CreateMessageKeysTask) {
    destDir = "bundle-common/src/";
    outputClass = "common.messages.MessageKeys";
}
```

or

```
task (CreateMessageKeys, type: CreateMessageKeysTask) {
    destDir = "bundle-common/src/";
    outputClass = "common.messages.MessageKeys";
}
```

---

Irrelevant to this question:

In your second example, perhaps the task `CreateMessageKeys` does not exist yet when this is evaluated. One possible workaround would be the following:

```
subprojects.each {
    it.afterEvaluate {
         it.test.dependsOn(...)
    }
}
```

Or simply putting the task definition above this block could resolve this.

Comment: I put the task definition above this block  but no luck

Comment: @SwapnilKotwal did the afterEvaluate solution also not work? If not, can you show us the output of `gradle tasks` (remove the dependsOn block first)

Comment: outside of `allprojects{}` & `subprojects{}` blocks I've many tasks like `task copyLibs{}` , `task createMessageKeys{}` etc but in `gradle tasks` output, none of these `tasks` are shown. 

But, in `conImage.dependsOn` I've used all above tasks and those works perfectly

Comment: The problem is not all sub-module are having `it.test` i.e. `test` is missing in sub-module and shall we filter those modules?

Comment: I tried `subprojects.each {
    if (!it.name.equalsIgnoreCase('lib-another-module') && !it.name.equalsIgnoreCase('lib-another-module1') ) {
        it.afterEvaluate {
            it.test.dependsOn('CreateMessageKeys')
        }
    }
}` but still same error

Comment: `No signature of method: java.lang.String.dependsOn() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [CreateMessageKeys]
  Possible solutions: respondsTo(java.lang.String)`

Comment: @SwapnilKotwal That's a new criteria you didn't specify. You should be able to write some groovy code that uses `afterEvaluate` and `tasks.findByName` to check for the `test` task. I'd recommend opening a new question or looking for a similar one

Comment: I found this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228458/2232127